# Append parent dropdown using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, colorbox

Is there a way to append a dropdown from one php page to another? I'm using a colorbox called from page1.

On php page2 :

```
<form method="post" id="add_me" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
<p>     
    <input type="text" name="desc" id="desc" value="<?php echo $new0;?>">
</p> 
<input type="submit" name="button" value="Continue" />
</form>
```

On php page 1:

```
<input class="iframe" href="page2.php" type="submit" name="submit_new" value="" />
<select name="selection" id="selection" > 
            <?php 
            while ($myrow = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
            ?> 
            <option>                            
            <?php echo $myrow['desc'];?>                
            </option>                                   
            <?php 
            } 
            ?> 
            </select> 
<div name="just_text" id="just_text" ></div>
```

Using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   

        $(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"50%", height:"50%"});        
         $('#add_me').submit(function(){

                $(':input').each(function(){                        
                      window.parent.$("#selection").text(parent.$("#selection").text() + $(this).val());
window.parent.$("#just_text").append(parent.$("#just_text").text() + $(this).val());                      
                });                 
                return false;                   
    });             
    });
```

This successfully appends to the div, however **I need to only append the dropdown selection**. The selection goes blank on submit while the text div gets appended. I assume my syntax is incorrect?

Comment: first thing i notice is you are missing value in `select option` tag             <option><?php echo $myrow['desc'];?></option> , so should be             <option value="<?php echo $myrow['desc'];?>"><?php echo $myrow['desc'];?></option>

Comment: Maybe an easier question is how do I append a dropdown from input text?

Comment: may b you edit code in your question n explain or wait someone who understand english better then me answer your question, all i see is php page 2 with `$new0` which i don't know from where it is coming and on php page 1 an input with href="page2.php" why href="page2.php" inside input, and then jQuery script, better create a fiddle